# How to fix "My Phone Number - Unknown" on Nexus 5?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, settings, nexus-5, sim-card

I had a standard SIM card, but I bought Nexus 5 and changed it for micro SIM card with saving my phone number. Now in Settings when I want find information about my phone number I only see "Unknown". I understand that the new micro SIM card doesn't have my phone number in memory, but maybe can I fix it in some way?

Comment: I think if you set up a default profile (the little person in the notification bar ) with your number and name, it should make that the owner of the phone, and maybe it'll update itself

Comment: @ProbablyThis but in profile settings for person in the notification bar I can change only my name and avatar...How to change phone number?